# Can a faulty CPU fan affect the screen

Tags: boot, display, cpu, hardware-failure, fan

I have a Toshiba Satellite L650D laptop, which for some reason doesn't really want to work any more. Basically, if I start it up, the screen doesn't show squat. As far as I can tell it doesn't even turn on, there's no backlight or anything, it looks exactly the same as it does when it's off. The LED lights flash, I can hear the HDD spinning, if there's a disc in the CD/DVD drive that spins, but no screen activity at all.

I opened it up and investigated, and it appears that the CPU fan doesn't spin either. It's not clogged or anything, it just doesn't move.

I understand that this isn't really a troubleshooting website and that a forum would be better suited to actually help fix my computer, but I want to ask this question: does the screen refuse to work due to the fan's failure? That is, can a faulty fan cause this screen problem? Maybe vice versa, does the screen affect the fan? And maybe any ideas as to what the issue could be?

If you need any more info please say.

Comment: `I understand that this isn't really a troubleshooting website.` This is false, we help people with problems like this all day.

Comment: the fan not turning on could be a motherboard issue, and no the screen should work regardless if the fan is on or off. If the fan is damaged and has not worked for sometime, it could of caused your cpu to fry? not really sure with the information you've given thusfar

Comment: Fan not spinning might be just that the CPU isn't heating. Otherwise it doesn't look like a "screen" problem but just that the PC doesn't boot up. You should try to connect an external monitor (on the VGA port for exemple) to see if it shows anything.

Comment: @Sickest: I understand that, but what I meant by "troubleshooting" was sort of like where you would ask questions and walk someone through methods to pinpoint and fix the problem. As this is a Q&A site, it doesn't really allow for such in-depth discussion and really should be fixable with a single answer.

Comment: @piernov: I tried hooking it up to the TV via HDMI, nothing shows up there either. I feel like it's an issue with the video card, not just the screen itself.

Comment: Can be something other than the video card. Another thing on the motherboard itself. But here, yes, the main problem experienced on laptop is a de-soldered GPU. The second one is a power supply (either in the external power supply, delivering insufficient current, or on a component of the motherboard, for exemple there are often bad capacitors on desktop motherboard).

A wrong flashed BIOS can cause this too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible in a laptop that the cooling not functioning could cause the GPU section or an on-die gpu item to fail to render to the screen properly, and it remains black.  also to fail terribly and effect other stuff communicating to it.

Assuming a really well done protection, it would also be possible that the driver (curcuit) for the lighting would be disengaged if the fan was not showing operational, or temps were to high, that assumes a really well thought out design.  I don't think many of these devices have thought things out that far, but the newer phone and tablets are starting to apply these methods for protecting the lighting aspect better.

Very likely that the lighting driver has components that would safety fail on overheat, this safety on the components would work again after cooled proper, possibly requiring a power off cycle first. With the speed at which your light goes off, this does not sound like the case.

And last but certannly not least, if there was not any proper cooling in the machine, there are a lot of lighting driver curcuits that would simply fail, and have to be replaced, because a component failed in them.
A friend of mine finds many screen items, sold used, that the lighting curcuit item is the only thing wrong, after lots of his time and little money he would replace them and all was well.

I am not that good with laptops, so a real laptop user would know better.  But there is always the fully "reset" things idea that I wonder if you tried yet?
To pull all the power out (battery etc) and hold the power down for a while.  WHY?  the method recommended like this drops all power off everything, then clears the tiny bit of power in the capacitors.  That would force every curcuit stuff in the whole thing to be reset (other than the coin battery backup stuff).  It does not fix anything , and rarely is the answer, but we do it anyways :-)

The web shows some other users with the similar problem, one it was the connections. With these thin tiny ribbon connection for going around hinged areas, that do not always stay "well connected".  If you get back in there that might be another thing to check.  I get the same thing with other portable devices, Just one connection of the row flaking out and the whole screen is off again.